# Can I determine which vendor a libOpenCL.so belongs to?

Tags: opencl, vendor

I'm looking at an orphan `libOpenCL.so` somewhere. I'm trying to figure out more about it, and specifically - which vendor and perhaps which version it is.

Is that possible? And if it is - how do I go about it?